# serializing an array with image paths into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I read that serialize are bad in most cases, [Is it good practice to use serialize in PHP in order to store data into the DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600956/is-it-good-practice-to-use-serialize-in-php-in-order-to-store-data-into-the-db).

In my case, I am not sure if there is a better way than serializing.

I have client side send images of houses to server. In the db there is a house table, attributes: houseID, address, images, etc. For the images I am storing a key-value pair, `(imageName => imagePath)` I need both imageName and path because I am storing houseID as the 'imagePath' in my filesystem, but I want to display to user the proper name.

My question is, to serialize or not to serialize. If not how should tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of serializing, have two columns in MySQL: the `imageName` and `imagePath`.  You should be able to easily store them as separate columns and recreating the key-value pair in PHP is trivial.

Comment: but the key-value pair contain more than one elements for each houses, since each house will have more than 1 image, how does that work?

Comment: @user308553 then create another table with HouseImages.  This can have the house ID and the imageName/imagePath

Comment: what about efficiency? is it costly to do it like this instead of serializing?

Comment: @user308553 I doubt you will notice a performance difference.  If anything, my suggestion will be more efficient.