# Using mysql in array operator on a json encoded array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Im creating a search query for a dating website, using the IN array operator.

```
e.g SELECT * from 'users' where 'job' IN("1", "2", "3");
```

This has been working well until I have a column where the user can select multiple options.

```
e.g jobs ["1", "2"] is stored in the database.
```

So is it possible to use in array on a json array.

Are there any solutions, e.g a diffrent way to store the multiple options in the database?

image to help http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=287eqt3&s=8#.U01mma1dWrA

Comment: Someone REALLY need to read about **Database Normalization**

Comment: Read about data normalization. The column with multiple options should be its own table.

Comment: How is jobs ["1", "2"] stored in the database? As one single string?

Comment: Stored in a varchar column just like an json_encoded array, best I can describe it, i'm still learning. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=287eqt3&s=8#.U01mma1dWrA

Answer (score 0):

You should [avoid storing serialized data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600956/is-it-good-practice-to-use-serialize-in-php-in-order-to-store-data-into-the-db) in your database.

Your users should have unique IDs.
Create another table "occupations" and insert each occupation into it, and assign each row to a user.

```
occupations
----------------------
name         user_id
______________________
Film         1
Singer       1
Copywriter   2
```

Then you can search for keywords like film.

```
SELECT * FROM `occupations` WHERE name LIKE "%Film%"
```

And you got all users assigned with occupation "Film".

Multiple:

```
SELECT * FROM `occupations` WHERE name LIKE "%Film%" OR name LIKE "%Singer%"
```

All users with film and singer.

Comment: I was wondering about doing that, but I was worried because I thought more queries might slow it down or something, thanks.