# json_decode returns NULL, json_last_error throws 0

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm passing a simple JSON array with 4 words to PHP. I want to store that array in a database after I serialize it. Since it's an Ajax call I can only investigate any echoed values by `json_encode` and alerting them in AJAX success function.

Here's my code:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(ans);
//if I alert jsonString - it shows the proper array
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: jsonString, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("error");     
    }
});
```

That's what I do in PHP with the array:

```
$answerAr = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$answers = serialize($answerAr);
```

If I echo the `json_encode`(`$answerAr`) it alerts NULL in Ajax and `$answers` turns into '`N;`'

`Json_last_error` returns 0.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600956/is-it-good-practice-to-use-serialize-in-php-in-order-to-store-data-into-the-db) thread :)

Comment: There is no value with the key `jsonString` in the post data. That is what you named in on the client side. There is no way for PHP to know that automagically. Just use `data: ans,`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: @PeeHaa changes made  - but it still gives NULL

Comment: Have you also read the two resources Iinked or do you want us to debug your code for you?

Comment: Have you tried using php://input ?

Comment: @PeeHaa I tried it - I cannot see any var_dumps in the console - errors are: Notice: undefined index data - it's for the '$answerAr = json_decode($_POST['data']);'

Comment: Could you print out the var jsonString? I think this is the key

Comment: @Eason.Luo I was trying to pass JSON data directly - the solutions to this are already contained in the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're posting data directly to PHP, you'll have to use `php://input` and parse that; data given in JSON isn't form data, and wont auto-populate the request superglobals (`$_GET`, `$_POST`).

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Most frameworks do this transparently for you and populate a request object with data in it. You should probably check if the request sends JSON data in the body via headers (`Content-Type`, `Accept: application/json`, etc)

Alternatively, you can change your AJAX call to give it an array key:

```
$.ajax({
  data: {data: jsonString},
  // etc
});
```

Which will then be accessible as `$_POST["data"]`

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax data attribute to like this and try

> data: {json: jsonString}

and in the php script you can access it by

> $answerAr = json_decode($_POST['json']);